# I need a JwtDecoder bean, can I autoconfigure this?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have this problem:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Method springSecurityFilterChain in
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration
> required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that could not be
> found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' in your
> configuration.

If I add this to my spring boot project, everything works as intended:

```
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.keycloak.jwt.issuer-uri}")
private String issuerUri;

@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);
}
```

My application.properties:

`spring.security.oauth2.keycloak.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev`

Is it possible to somehow remove the `@Bean` method and still make it work? Somehow make the project to create that bean for itself?

Comment: Can you please share the dependencies you are using in this project.

Comment: Facing same issue. Were you able to resolve the issue?@EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Using spring-boot-starter-security,spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client,spring-security-oauth2-resource-server and spring-security-oauth2-jose as dependencies in pom file.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this post](https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/issues/48), adding the following configuration to properties.yml file will eliminate the error:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://dev-.....okta.com/oauth2/default
```

Where *jwk-set-uri* is the issuer id of the authorization server.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the same issue because I set only ***jwt-set-uri*** and when I set ***issuer-uri***, my project starts fine.

And configuration in propertie file:

```
spring:
 security:
  oauth2:
   resourceserver:
    jwt:
     issuer-uri: http://localhost:8082/realms/dev_spring_security
     jwt-set-uri: http://localhost:8082/realms/dev_spring_security/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```